# Trying to Produce a Schwabacher Lettrine

Tags: fonts, luatex, lettrine, drop-cap, yfonts

I am trying to produce a Schwabacher lettrine with the `\textswab` command in the following manner:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{type1cm,lettrine}
\usepackage{yfonts}

\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\color{brown!42!black}\textswab{}}
\renewcommand{\LettrineTextFont}{\textswab}
\begin{document}
\Huge
\thispagestyle{empty}

\lettrine[lines=2,loversize=.65,findent=-.13em,nindent=2.5pt]{T}{exts:wab Lettrine}
\end{document}
```

But I get the following output:

[image]

QUESTION: This type of code has worked for me in the past with a font other than `\textswab`. Can anyone see what I may be doing wrong? I am compiling with `lualatex`.

Thank you.

Comment: `\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\color{brown!42!black}\swabfamily}`

Comment: @Thérèse Though that produces the desired lettrine, for some reason the size of the lettrine is reduced to that of a regular letter. Moreover, its position is dropped considerably. The only way I have been able to fix it is with this: `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \DeclareFontShape{LY}{yswab}{m}{n}{<->yswab}{}`. Although this works fine, the document I intend to use it for, I recall, uses `fontspec`---so there may be a conflict with `[T1]fontenc`. Thank you for your helpful comment.

Comment: Get rid of `loversize=.65` and `\Huge`, etc., and then make adjustments.

Comment: @Thérèse It seems that `[T1]{fontenc}` may not be needed after all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is that you wanted to use `\swabfamily`, which *switches to* Schwabacher until the end of the group or environment, and not `\textswab{}`, which only affects the text inside the brackets or the following token.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lettrine}

% Workaround for the limited sizes of uyswab.fd:
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{yswab}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{yswab}{m}{n}{
   <->yswab }{}

\usepackage{oldgerm}

\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\color{brown!42!black}\swabfamily}
\renewcommand{\LettrineTextFont}{\swabfamily}


\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\lettrine[lines=2,loversize=.65,findent=-.13em,nindent=2.5pt]{T}{exts:wab Lettrine}\\
A line of Computer Modern
\end{document}
```

[image: yswab font sample]

I took the minor liberty of replacing `yfonts` with `oldgerm`, a package that is part of the core LaTeX distribution and still maintained.  Whichever package you use, the stock definition of the font declares only a few limited font sizes (a holdover from the original METAFONT design), so it is necessary to override the declaration in `uswab.fd` in order to enable the scalable font size that `\lettrine` wants.

Comment: Thank you for this post; however, with `yfonts`, I was able to make presentable the lettrine with `\DeclareFontShape{LY}{yswab}{m}{n}{<->yswab}{}`; that is, the output resembled the picture I posted except the lettrine was displayed with the desired font. Though I have tried, I have not been able to get the lettrine in your code to be displayed higher than the rest of the text. Replacing `yswab` with `swabfamily` in the `\DeclareFontShape` command does not work. Perhaps you might consider modifying your answer so I may see how to do this with your code. Many thanks.

Comment: @mlchristians I ended up using a slightly-different workaround for the fixed font sizes, but I’ve revised as you suggested.

Comment: Hope this is useful.

Comment: Many thanks. It is.

Answer (score 3):

If you compile with `luatex` or `xetex`, you should use Opentype fonts (.ttf or .otf).
Among "Fraktur" fonts, I know of two of them: `UnifrakturMaguntia.ttf` (http://unifraktur.sourceforge.net/maguntia.html) and `QTFraktur.otf` (included in TeXLive). Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{UnifrakturMaguntia.ttf}
%\setmainfont{QTFraktur.otf}

\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\color{red}}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\lettrine[lines=2,loversize=.65,findent=-.13em,nindent=2.5pt]{T}{extswab Lettrine}

 \end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

**EDIT 2022/07/20:** The yfonts are now available in OpenType format, so you can just type:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{oldgerm-otf}

\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\color{brown!42!black}\swabfamily}
\renewcommand{\LettrineTextFont}{\swabfamily}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\lettrine[lines=2,loversize=.65,findent=-.13em,nindent=2.5pt]{T}{exts:wab Lettrine}\\
A line of Computer Modern
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

See documentation file `yfonts-otf.pdf` for more details.

Comment: Nice addition to the set of OpenType fonts!